# Column names are not all exported

Tags: sas

I have sas dataset and try to export to csv. It contains around 5000 columns and each columns are needed to export. But when I export the data, all rows are included but only around first 2000 column names are included.  Do anyone know how to include all column name here?  I checked something about Lrecl may help but I don't know how to apply to column names.

Comment: How did you "export" the file?  Show the code you used.  Or if you used some menu explain it detail what you did.

Comment: @Tom I tried firstly simple  export from export option; I also used simple code as   `proc export data=Tmp1yr 
       outfile='temp.csv';

       run;`

Comment: Please post additional info as edits to your question, don't keep it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use PROC EXPORT to write a delimited file. To write the data you can use a trivial data step.

```
data _null_;
   set mydata ;
   file "myfile" dsd ;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

To include a header row you will need to do a little more work.

First get the list of variables and use it to write the header row.

```
proc transpose data=mydata(obs=0) out=names; 
  var _all_;
run;

data _null_;
  file "myfile" dsd ;
  set names;
  put _name_ @ ;
run;
```

Then you can use the MOD option of the FILE statement in the step that appends the actual data.

```
data _null_;
   set mydata ;
   file "myfile" dsd mod;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

Make sure that you set the record length long enough to hold all of your variable names. The default record length of 32,767 bytes would only leave enough room for the average variable name to be 5 characters and still fit 5,000 names.  Add the  `lrecl=500000` option to the `FILE` statements. Too large a value shouldn't be a problem as long as it is not more than SAS on your operating system allows. Generally the upper bound is on the order of 1 to 10 million characters.

Comment: It doesn't show as expect. The columns names are separated  into three lines in excel. And the break location is same as the point where SAS stops to export my columns names.   But at least it exports all column names only not in the right format.

Comment: Added description about how to change the logical record length (maximum line length) to allow more room per line for both names and data.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `EXPORT` `FILE=` using a fileref that has a large `LRECL=`.  Export will clip a line (max number of characters of a line) according to the `LRECL` setting.

Example:

```
data have;
  do row = 1 to 10;
    array my_column_name (5000) (1230001:1235000); * initialize the array with some large integers;
    output;
  end;
run;

* fileref for export.  lines output will 'clip' output at 1,000,000 characters;
filename widefile 'c:\temp\my_wide_data.csv' lrecl=1000000;

proc export data=have dbms=csv replace file=widefile;
run;

filename widefile;  * clear the fileref;
```

The system option LRECL is used by the Export wizard, and the system LRECL setting can not exceed 32767 (and the SAS default setting for LRECL is 32767).  That is why the export wizard output was clipped.